# Variance of Distributions from the Exponential Family

Tags: probability, variance, exponential-family

I want to understand how the variance of an exponential family behaves. To take a very concrete example. Let consider the unit ball $B$ in d dimensions.

Consider the following distribution over unit ball (parametrized by $\theta$)
$$P_{\theta}(x) = \frac{exp(-\theta^T x)}{Z(\theta)}$$

where $Z(\theta)$ is the normalizing constant.

$P_0$ is the uniform distribution

Are the following statements true?

$\forall \theta \;\;$ Variance of $P_0$ $\geq$ Variance of $P_{\theta}$

More generally

$\forall \theta_1, \theta_2 \|\theta_1\| > \|\theta_2\| \;\;$  Variance of $P_{\theta_1}$ $\leq$ Variance of $P_{\theta_2}$

Comment: By variance here do you mean covariance matrix, as $x$ is d-dimensional? If so, how do you define $\leq$ for covariance matrices?

Comment: What about a beta distribution with $\alpha,\beta\leq1$, which is from an exponential family and has more variance than the uniform?

Comment: @JuhoKokkala - My bad. I was a bit sloppy with my notations. To start with I am fine with getting this for d = 1 where there is no confusion. In higher dimensions I would replace $\leq$ in the Positive Semi Definite sense applied to the covariance matrix

Comment: @ChristophHanck - I am not totally sure if this answers my question. To my understanding the Beta distribution needs a reparametrization to be expressed as an exponential family distribution. In that case I dont think the precise form of my question holds.

Comment: If it's a member of the exponential family, it's a member of the exponential family regardless of parameterization.  It may be that the standard way of writing the distribution doesn't use the "natural" parameterization, where "natural" refers to the exponential family-related definition of same, but the  distribution itself is still a member of the exponential family.

Comment: @jbowman - but does it it fit the definition of the problem? I am only comparing the two distributions I mentioned in the description. For instance I have almost surely verified the problem I posted for d = 1

Comment: The discussion would surely benefit if you posted that solution, and if/how it depends on the parametrization.